# Django: Startapp Generated files into existing project folder

Tags: python, django

I want to place django app files into generated Django project folder .

```
MyProject/
    MyProject/
       settings.py
       urls.py
```

here i want to insert my Django app files like, views.py, admin.py, models.py etc into same `MyProject` folder itself. we can do the same by copy paste after app was created. but i want to know is their any magic we  can achieve the same while executing this command?

```
django-admin startapp MyApp <directory>
```

I dont want to create `Myapp` folder instead `Myapp/*` should be move onto `Myproject/` itself. without doing copy paste thing.

so finally i want my Project folder should be like this,

```
MyProject/
        MyProject/
           admin.py
           models.py 
           settings.py
           urls.py   
           views.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command to run from same direcory. If you change directory then change in path also:

```
django-admin startproject myproject
django-admin startapp myapp myproject\myproject\
```

command sample:

```
E:\write here>django-admin startproject myproject

E:\write here>dir myproject\myproject
 Volume in drive E has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ****-****

 Directory of E:\write here\myproject\myproject

03-06-2017  11.53 AM    <DIR>          .
03-06-2017  11.53 AM    <DIR>          ..
03-06-2017  11.53 AM             3,103 settings.py
03-06-2017  11.53 AM               766 urls.py
03-06-2017  11.53 AM               396 wsgi.py
03-06-2017  11.53 AM                 0 __init__.py
               4 File(s)          4,265 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  80,954,753,024 bytes free

E:\write here>django-admin startapp myapp myproject\myproject\
CommandError: E:\write here\myproject\myproject\__init__.py already exists, overlaying a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files
```

don't worry about above error because it is just notifying you that `__init__.py` is not to be overwrite.

Comment: super its work what i want . but we should override already exist otherwise it wont create sub files... how to override if it is exist?

Comment: I am also getting this error ( CommandError ).

Comment: I understand you asked to ignore this.But how do create the app anyway?